# Avoid MySQL 'using temporary' in certain cases

Tags: mysql, optimization, temp-tables, explain

I have two tables, `users` and `followers`:

Table `users`:

```
id          INT, PRIMARY_KEY
name        VARCHAR
joined      INT
```

This table is indexed on `id` and `joined`.

Table 'followers':

```
user        INT
follows     INT
```

This table is indexed on `users` and `follows`.

This query finds the names of all users followed by a particular user who joined after a particular time. The results need to be
in reverse chronological order.

```
SELECT u.name 
FROM users u, followers f
WHERE f.user = X
AND f.follows = u.id
AND u.joined > 1234
ORDER BY u.joined DESC
```

Now, when user X has a large number of followers, EXPLAIN gives the following:

```
id      key             extra
-----------------------------------
u       joined          Using where
f       follows         Using index
```

So far so good. (The 'using where' is due to some other clauses I've removed for brevity).

But, when user X has a small number of followers, this happens:

```
id      key             extra
-----------------------------------
f       follows         Using temporary, using filesort
u       joined          Using where
```

If I omit the `ORDER BY`, I get:

```
id      key             extra
-----------------------------------
f       follows         
u       joined          Using where
```

The MySQL optimiser seems to be inspecting the number of rows it has to deal with, and if its small, doing the
`followers` table first. It seems to ignore the `ORDER BY` in its optimisation steps, resulting in a slower query due
to the temporary table.

So (finally), my question is: is it possible to force the order in which MySQL performs table searches, and in the likely event this isn't possible, is there another way to get rid of `using temporary`?

Comment: How many records do you get via that slow query of yours when user has small amount of followers?

Comment: Probably around 100; a large number could be in the thousands.

Comment: What do you get if your query is this: `SELECT 
u.name 

FROM users u

INNER JOIN followers f ON
f.follows = u.id

WHERE 
f.user = 'xxx' 
AND 
u.joined > 1234 
ORDER BY u.joined DESC`

Comment: No change I'm afraid, still uses temporary.

Comment: Yes, but is it any faster? Using temporary isn't the issue, MySQL does that when it has to order the records in non-insert order.

Comment: No, the execution time is about the same. My only thought is to omit the ORDER clause when X is small, then order the results at the web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL DOES offer a clause "STRAIGHT_JOIN" which tells it to do the join between tables in the order you've provided.  Since you are looking for a single specific "Follower User" put the follower table up front and join from that... Try something like

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      u.name
  from
     followers f
        join Users u
           on f.follows = u.id
          and u.joined > 1234
  where
     f.user = X
  order by 
     u.joined DESC
```

This should FORCE Starting with the "Followers" table, specific for user ID = X, then join out to the users table as SECONDARY based on the rows returned from f.user = X.  Make sure your Followers table has an index where "user" is in the first position (in case your index on both columns was (follows, user), it SHOULD be (user, follows). The smallest granularity on your query basis is the one person inquiring about... that comes in FIRST.

Comment: Excellent - I had not heard of straight_join, but does exactly what I need. Many thanks.